# Your system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation

Tags: windows, installation

I can't install any program and got error "Your system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation". How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you logged on as a user with administrative rights?

Comment: These restrictions are defined by what's called [Group Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy), where administrators can configure a wide variety of restrictions and system settings to suit various needs for use in business environments, etc.  Note that the Group Policy Editor, `gpedit.msc`, is only available on Windows XP Professional; Windows Vista Business, Enterprise, and Ultimate; Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, and Ulitmate; and Windows 8 Pro and Enterprise editions.  The consumer-oriented versions of Windows do not have this feature.

Comment: This should be reopened as a real question. The correct answer is identified and accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to change the `DisableMSI` value in the registry: under the key `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer`, set the value of `DisableMSI` to `0`.

Answer (score 12):

If you are in a business, government, educational, or other environment that is not your own personal home network, that sort of message generally indicates that the system administrator does not want unknown and unapproved software installed on computer systems for which they have responsibility.  This restriction could be in place for a variety of reasons (national security restrictions; health, financial, or other privacy concerns; software licensing restrictions; or simply not wanting to support random software installed by users).

Your best course of action if the computer and network are not legally yours is to contact the system administrator for assistance.  They may be willing to grant an exception to the policy if you can make the case that you really do need the software.

Comment: +1 for not supporting random software

Comment: +1 also for that.  If the computer isn't yours, don't touch!!  As someone that in the past has had to clean up the messes that installing unauthorized software creates for sysadmins, I can't say it enough.  If you want to install something for work, talk with the admins about the app you want to use.  Otherwise, go home and install it on your personal computer.  If this is your personal computer and you don't have rights to it, that's a whole other issue.

Comment: That's my personal computer. I'm sure my user account have administrator right.
I download and run some files from online. After that i got this error and i think my pc is Virus effect.

I follow the instruction from http://systemadministratorhassetpoliciestopreventthisinstallation.com/ . But that can't fix my problem.

Comment: If it is your personal computer then it is possible that you have a virus or other malware.  If you can't find out what your are infected with then wiping and reinstalling the OS may be your only course of action.

Comment: Edit your question to indicate that it's your own computer and why you suspect a virus.

Comment: @Mike Chess: Maybe you should help solve the issue instead of projecting your conjectures. It's entirely possible to have this issue on a personal or test system that you have the right to modify.

Answer (score 4):

Use a portable version of the application or contact the administrator.

Comment: +1 for portable suggestion, however this sometimes is infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft must have disabled MSI installation for a reason. There is probably some kind of security vulnerability in it. It doesn't make sense to change the settings of your computer to permanently allow all MSI installations. The correct thing to do is not change your registry, it is to go to Start->Programs->Accessories and right click on Command and choose "Run as Administrator" then navigate to the folder where the installer file is and run it. This will bypass this message for this installation only.

Comment: This problem is more insidious than I thought, and the method I describe above will not work under certain scenarios. For example, if you want to uninstall an MSI installed program from Add Remove Programs, you can't.

Comment: Your method doesn't work.