# Network administartor has applied a Group policy that prevents installation

Tags: installation, group-policy

My official laptop has Windows Vista installed in it. While I have admin permission to install any software, I couldn't install "Google Talk Video chat" plugin. When I attempt it I get this message:

> "your network administrator has applied a Group policy that prevents
>   installation"

I tried opening group policy editor console by gpedit.msc, and went through it, couldn't find anything that helps me.

Since it is a laptop I don't have to be connected to my domain network always. If somehow I could install the Google talk video plugin, it would be helpful.

Comment: If its blocked by group policy, then there may be a reason for it.  Talk to the admins at your work to see why.  Circumventing group policy is a fireable offense in many companies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [System Policy won't let me install TurboTax](http://superuser.com/questions/280134/system-policy-wont-let-me-install-turbotax) also: http://superuser.com/questions/141752/your-system-administrator-has-set-policies-to-prevent-this-installation

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a couple of choices here. You could :

a) talk to the network administrator and ask him/her to correct it

b) if it's limiting you through their network that your connected to via wifi you could go home and download it.

c) If going home doesn't work it might be because it's still checking with it's home (your work) in order to fix this you must find what IP that home has temporarily block it and hope that it defaults into giving you permission when it can't connect.

d) If your network admin is serious about this stuff it's installed on local and you'll be forced to perform action a.